# Lodash's sortedIndexOf vs indexOf in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I recently read on https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#sortedIndexOf that using lodash's `sortedIndexOf(myArray.sort(), element)` is equivalent to using `myArray.sort().indexOf(element)`. But as far as i know indexOf just uses a naive search algorithm iterating through the whole array in the worst case, while sortedIndexOf does a binary search on the array.

Am I missing something in the implementation of indexOf that makes it perform similarly to lodash's binary search or is the claim wrong?.

Comment: There is no claim regarding the relative efficiency of the two approaches. `sortedIndexOf` should be faster for large arrays that are known to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a mistake at the site. Their replacement sorts the array, but the point of `sortedIndexOf()` is that it assumes that the array is already sorted. This is more expensive than `_.sortedIndexOf()` since it has to do both an O(N log N) sort and an O(N) search, while `_.sortedIndexOf()` can do O(log N) binary search. And it also modifies the array by sorting it; this might not be wanted.

And if the array is already sorted, there's no need to call `.sort()` in the replacement code.

I think the author of that entry simply misunderstood the point of `_.sortedIndexOf()`.